# Newbie in R: Cant show just 2 out of 3 categorial variables, cant rename legend and other stuff

Tags: r, ggplot2

i'm newbie and i really need some help with my data. First of all, i can't change the legend to show the shape of points. And secondly i need to show just 2 out of 3 categorial variables (just 2 and 3, not 1).

```
alikvot <- data_oliga$alikvot

#selecting categorial variables

alikvot = sample(c("1", "2", "3"), 648, replace = TRUE)
alikvot = as.factor(alikvot)
alikvot = cbind(data_oliga, alikvot)

#creating scatterplot

Graf_oliga = ggplot(data = data_oliga, aes (x = konc_v, y = Area, 
                                            colour = factor(alikvot), shape = alikvot, group = alikvot)) 

Graf_oliga + 
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  scale_shape_identity() +
  xlab("Abs * 400") +
  labs(colour = "Alikvot", shape = alikvot) +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x)) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDUbW.png)

I know that the code is so messed up.
Thanks for any help

Data looks like that:

| ID oliga | alikvot | Area | Abs * 400 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 39/18 | 1 | 1234 | 56789 |
| 39/18 | 1 | 3465 | 56789 |
| 39/18 | 2 | 1456 | 56789 |
| 39/18 | 2 | 3546 | 23187 |
| 39/18 | 3 | 11681 | 78624 |
| 39/18 | 3 | 1681 | 12357 |
| 50/18 | 1 | 45654 | 23394 |
| 50/18 | 1 | 1156 | 14653 |
| 50/18 | 2 | 5467 | 42358 |
| 50/18 | 2 | 9241 | 32186 |
| 50/18 | 3 | 7864 | 32168 |
| 50/18 | 3 | 6821 | 48918 |

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help us to help you could you please make your issue reproducible by sharing a sample of your **data**? See [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Simply type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 20))` for the first twenty rows of data.

Comment: .. . for the legend you could try with `scale_shape_identity(guide = "legend")` as `scale_xxx_identity` will not create a legend by default. Your second issue sounds like a filtering issue, i.e. instead of making use of the whole data you could use `data_oliga[data_oliga$alkivot %in% c(2, 3), ]`

Comment: added table with datas.

Comment: scale_shape_identity(guide = "legend") just showed another legend with just shapes, no colours. Also it somehow showed 5 shapes instead of 3. Filtering also didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. If you want the legends to get merged you have to map the same variables on the `color` and `shape` aesthetic, i.e. `factor(alikvot)`, and (!!) set the same labels inside `labs()`.

Not sure what you tried to achieve with `scale_shape_identity`. So I simply removed it. If you want specific shapes then make use of `scale_shape_manual(values = c(...))`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

data_oliga_filtered <- data_oliga[data_oliga$alikvot %in% c(2, 3),]
Graf_oliga = ggplot(data = data_oliga_filtered, aes (x = `Abs.*.400`, y = Area, 
                                            colour = factor(alikvot), shape = factor(alikvot)))
Graf_oliga + 
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  xlab("Abs * 400") +
  labs(colour = "Alikvot", shape = "Alikvot") +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x)) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x))
```

[image]